# Determine whether or not a company has acquired others using NLP

Tags: python, nlp

I'm trying to build a Python script to identify whether a company has acquired others. For this, I intend to seach Google for " acquisition", and parse the titles of the first N pages. Then, from the titles that have indicators that there was an actual acquisition, I want to extract the name of the company that was acquired, and I also want to provide a confidence metric. And obviously, it also has to make sure that it was the company I'm looking for that acquired another one, and not the other way around.

I have some experience with NER, but with this specific NLP task I don't know where to start. Is there something already implemented for such task?

Comment: This is a collection of questions all together. What in particular have you tried and what are you focusing on, for a start?